# How to use trace to step through S4 generic function into method actually dispatched?

Tags: r, r-s4

I have a simple set of S4 classes with a single generic methods.  I want be able to use `trace()` to debug S4 methods.

```
$ cat s4class.R
add<-function(a,b){
    d=0 
    e=9 
    return(a+b)
}  
setClass('astrophys_object',
        representation(mass="numeric", spin="numeric", radius="numeric", 
                       v="numeric", x="numeric", charge="numeric"), 
        prototype(mass=1, spin=1.92e41, radius=6.957e8, v=c(0,0,0),
                  x=c(0,0,0), charge=0)
)
setClass('star',
        contains="astrophys_object",
        representation(type="character", metallicity="numeric", temp="numeric"),
        prototype(type="MS", metallicity=0.0122, temp=5700)
)
setClass('galaxy',
        contains="astrophys_object",
        representation(type="character", sfr="numeric"),
        prototype(type="spiral", sfr=1.65, mass=5.8e11, spin=1.0e67)
)
setGeneric("spin_object", function(object){
    standardGeneric("spin_object")
})
setMethod("spin_object", signature(object = "galaxy"), function(object){
    object@spin = 66
    return(object)
})
setMethod("spin_object", signature(object = "star"), function(object){
    object@spin = 99
    return(object)
})
```

I am able to step through the test function `add()`.

```
> trace(add, browser, at=1)
[1] "add"
> add(9,8)
Tracing add(9, 8) step 1 
Called from: eval(expr, p)
Browse[1]> n
debug: `{`
Browse[2]> n
debug at R/stackoverflow.R#19: d = 0
Browse[2]> n
debug at R/stackoverflow.R#20: e = 9
Browse[2]> n
debug at R/stackoverflow.R#21: return(a + b)
Browse[2]> n
[1] 17
```

Now let's try to step through the `spin_object` generic method.

```
> trace(spin_object, browser, at=1)
Constructing traceable class “nonstandardGenericFunctionWithTrace”
Environment of class “nonstandardGenericFunction” is locked; using global environment for new class
[1] "spin_object"
attr(,"package")
[1] ".GlobalEnv"
> s<-new('star')
> spin_object(s)
Tracing spin_object(s) step 1 
Called from: eval(expr, p)
Browse[1]> n
debug: `{`
Browse[2]> n
debug at R/stackoverflow.R#45: standardGeneric("spin_object")
Browse[2]> s
debugging in: loadMethod(function (object) 
{
    object@spin = 99
    return(object)
}, "spin_object", <environment>)
debug: standardGeneric("loadMethod")
Browse[3]> n   ##### <<<---- If I step here, I end up stepping into "loadMethod" NOT spin_object
exiting from: loadMethod(function (object) 
{
    object@spin = 99
    return(object)
}, "spin_object", <environment>)
An object of class "star"
Slot "type":
[1] "MS"

Slot "metallicity":
[1] 0.0122

Slot "temp":
[1] 5700

Slot "mass":
[1] 1

Slot "spin":
[1] 99

Slot "radius":
[1] 695700000

Slot "v":
[1] 0 0 0

Slot "x":
[1] 0 0 0

Slot "charge":
[1] 0
```

**QUESTION** How do I actually step through the `spin_object` dispatched for `star` class? If I try to step at `Browser[3]`, I end up stepping into `loadMethod` and **NOT** the method that is being dispatched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, I need to specify the signature argument to `trace()`

```
trace(what='spin_object', tracer=browser, at=1, signature='star')
```